# What's the difference between these SQL syntaxes?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, create-table

I was looking for info on foreign keys.... AGAIN! ... and happened to notice on webschools.com they have different examples of the same thing.  for the foreign key example they have

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

now..........

what's the difference?...

How do I know which one I'm suppose to use for my database?  I have a feeling this will help resolve a lot of the confusion I'm having with SQL...

Comment: First of all you need to know what you are up to do? I mean what attributes do you need. There might be many examples but all these are just for test and these have different purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference in effect: They achieve exactly the same thing.

I prefer the in-line version, because it puts the fk definition as close to the column definition as possible.

There's a 3rd way - a separate `alter table` statement (which I think is the "official" way):

```
alter table orders
add contraint fk_PerOrders 
foreign key p_id references persons(p_id);
```

You may find some databases don't support one version or the other.

Comment: thanks! but still, I figured they do the same thing, but what are those different methods called?  Why do they exist?  I'm just wondering because I don't know SQL all that well yet and while looking at different tutorials I just see "SQL Syntax"... it didn't hit me until now that there were 3 different kinds.. lol.  I need to figure out which one works with what I use.

Answer (score 1):

All of them are doing same thing. Use the one which you feel is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

All do same (three ways):

- In first, you first defined `P_Id` as `int` then defined foreign key constraint.
- In second, `P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)`. `P_Id` is defecation and foreign key constraint defecation in same line.
- In third, `a foreign key constraint name` is also give `fk_PerOrders`. that can be `useful later when you wants to drop constraint`.  e.g.

> ALTER TABLE Orders
>       DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_PerOrders

Its always good practice to give name to a constraint.

Comment: `may be you are talking about this` [site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) their written clearly.